# Can't customize Theme / Next.js & Shadcn

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I try to customize theme by copy/paste style from https://ui.shadcn.com/themes to global.css yet it just does not work ..

Default and current global.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;
  --background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --background-start-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --background-end-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  }
}

body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent,
      rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
    )
    rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
}
```

Comment: You should try to add following theme code inside your global.css
@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: 0 0% 100%;
  }
  .dark {
    --background: 224 71.4% 4.1%;
  }
}